# i8kmon not working properly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, temperature

### Problem

I started to notice that the computer's fans turned on at full speed unnecessarily, so I installed the i8kmon service to control them. It seems that i8kmon is not able to control fans with i8kfan command until I disable bios fan control by hand.

### My setup

- Dell XPS 13 9380
- Ubuntu 18.04

### Logs

Service is running:

```
root@pl438-pro:/home/inzaghi# /etc/init.d/i8kmon status
● i8kmon.service - Dell laptop thermal monitoring
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/i8kmon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-05-07 09:58:26 CEST; 20min ago
     Docs: man:i8kmon
 Main PID: 1222 (tclsh)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/i8kmon.service
           └─1222 tclsh /usr/bin/i8kmon --nouserconfig

mai 07 10:18:40 pl438-pro i8kmon[1222]: temp, left fan state, right fan state, ac state: 50 0 0 0
```

Service detects high temperature, but the command is ignored:

```
May  7 10:14:32 pl438-pro i8kmon[1222]: temp, left fan state, right fan state, ac state: 65 0 0 0
May  7 10:14:32 pl438-pro i8kmon[1222]: # (65>=65), state=1, low=55, high=75
May  7 10:14:32 pl438-pro i8kmon[1222]: /usr/bin/i8kfan 1 1
May  7 10:14:34 pl438-pro i8kmon[1222]: temp, left fan state, right fan state, ac state: 65 0 0 0
```

Config file /etc/i8kmon.conf

```
# Sample i8kmon configuration file (/etc/i8kmon.conf, ~/.i8kmon).
set config(use_conf)    1

set config(auto)       1

# External program to control the fans
set config(i8kfan)      /usr/bin/i8kfan

# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose)     1

# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout)     2

# Temperature threshold at which the temperature is displayed in red
set config(t_high)      80

# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# These were tested on the I8000. If you have a different Dell laptop model
# you should check the BIOS temperature monitoring and set the appropriate
# thresholds here. In doubt start with low values and gradually rise them
# until the fans are not always on when the cpu is idle.
set config(0) {{0 0}  -1  60  -1  65}
set config(1) {{1 1}  50  70  55  75}
set config(2) {{2 2}  60  80  65  85}
set config(3) {{2 2}  70 128  75 128}

# Speed values are set here to avoid i8kmon probe them at every time it starts.
set status(leftspeed)   "0 1000 2000 3000"
set status(rightspeed)  "0 1000 2000 3000"

# end of file
```

### Workaround

Restarting the service with `/etc/init.d/i8kmon` changes nothing. I found that the BIOS also tries to control the fans, so I installed https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control via snap, executing `/snap/dell-bios-fan-control/2/dell-bios-fan-control 0` makes things work.

I thought that this setting was saved in the bios permanently, but it seems that I need to run it every time I boot my computer. Should I add it as a service?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: I finally made my workaround more "clean": I created a service that execute
`dell-bios-fan-control 0` on startup.

EDIT: Is not working anymore, or is working very randomly. I still need to run
`/snap/dell-bios-fan-control/2/dell-bios-fan-control 0` and restart the `i8kmod` to make it work.

<s>Seems that I forgot to add the module `dell-smm-hwmon` to `/etc/modules` with the config file `/etc/modprobe.d/dell-smm-hwmon.conf` as follow:</s>

```
options dell-smm-hwmon restricted=0
```

Now it works fine without setting anything.

Comment: You Sir are awesome!! I spent days playing around with my constantly running fans and tried probably any tools and configs there are. Finally `dell-bios-fan-control` provides me the power to control my system! I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Dell Precision 5540 by the way..

Answer (score 0):

snap version of dell-bios-fan-control was crashing for me on Ubuntu 22.04 and Dell Precision 5520:

```
# dell-bios-fan-control 0
ioperm:: Operation not permitted
ioperm:: Operation not permitted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've compiled it from source -  https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control - and it finally stops the fans!